# Google sheets, scale Axis to Date, not to item

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

So i have a simple line chart, it plots a value for each entry into the table it is made from.
Each only has 2 columns:
DateTime, and Value

The value is cumulative, so you expect and upward trending line.
The DateTime however, is arbitrary. In the sense that between row 1 and 2, could be 3 days, but between row 4 and 5 count be only 5 seconds.

For some reason, sheets insists on printing the X axis with all the dots equally spaced out, instead of being spaced out over the "time between" the 2 data points.

How do i convince sheets to reconsider? (The columns have been made type DateTime, they are not the default of "i am text" or whatever)

Comment: Consider sharing a copy of your sheet.

Comment: Nothing that sheet will tell you that the question did not. The problem doesn't seem all that complex to me. It just doesn't seem to have any option to alter it save for cheating with extra columns for the desired effect.

Comment: Same problem here.  Dates that are 3 months apart are same distance horizontally as dates that are just a few days apart, depending on how many dates I need to chart on horizontal axis.   Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found an ugly workaround for my particular use case based on this question/answer:

[How can I horizontally space data points on a chart when the dates are arbitrary?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/162200/how-can-i-horizontally-space-data-points-on-a-chart-when-the-dates-are-arbitrary?rq=1)

I had at most 4 data points in a month, so I made sure each month in my data range had 4 data points.  If a month had 0 dates charted, I'd add 4 dummy points.  If it had 1 date, I'd add 3 dummies, and so forth.

It doesn't quite scale right inside months, but it's an improvement. If you wanted it perfect you'd need to add an entry for every day of the range.